# how to cancel expiration of cached item

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

I have added one cache item in MemoryCache which is expired after every 10 minutes. But when it is expired I am calling one method which fetches the fresh data from the database & again Set the new cache item in MemoryCache with the same key. But if the exception is thrown in the Cache item removed call back method then item is removed from MemoryCache but new item is not getting added to cache. This cache item is used in the further operations.
How to handle this situation?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: I think I should remove AbsoluteExpiration & put some mechanism to remove & add new cache item in MemoryCache.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the cache data refreshed automaticaly when it expires put the GetFromDataBase call in with the GetData Method and call it if the cache returns nothing. That way the exception is passed back to the calling code and the next call will (hopefully) re populate the cache

ie (please excuse psudocode)

```
    public class data
    {
        public SomeData GetData(int id)
        {
            if (cache.Contains(id))
            {
                return cache[id];
            }
            else
            {
                SomeData data = GetDataFromDB(id);
                cache[id] = data;
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Or you can have this approach in place and the auto refresh as well. This way you can avoid the performance hit when accessing and expired item in most of the scenarios.

Comment: Can I stop expiration of cache item?

Comment: the cache expiration policy is up to you. this code just creates a fall back for when there is no cache. thus preventing the error you asked about in yoir question. @juan in my view the auto refresh tied to cache expiration is dangerous. but yes a seperate thread which populates the cache periodicaly could be good. you can also add further code to try and ensure that the db isnt hit multiple times in high volume multi theaded senarios

Comment: I have tried to update the old cached item in CacheEntryUpdateCallback method but newly added item is also removed automatically after the update callback.

Comment: @Ewan, current implementation is exactly similar as you said. The separate thread is populating data periodically & set it in cache. Previously the cache was updated in CacheEntryRemovedCallback. The problem with RemovedCallback is, it is called after removal of cachedItem so we dont have its old copy, in case there is any issue in setting up new cache item.